# Second order linear ODE with trigonometric coefficient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

Is there a theory and a name for the second order linear ODE with trigonometric coefficient (other than the Floquet theory)?

The equation in question, with $a$,$b$,$c$ periodic function containing only $\sin$ and $\cos$, is of the form:
\begin{equation}
a(t)\theta^{''}(t)+b(t)\theta^{'}(t)+c(t)\theta(t)=0
\end{equation}